# Isotopic diffeomorphisms of surface are diffeotopic?

Tags: differential-topology, diffeomorphism, mapping-class-group

Due to Epstain, if two homeomorphisms $f_0, f_1$ of a closed two-dimensional manifold $S$ are homotopic then they are isotopic. I've heard, that if $f_0, f_1$ are diffeomorphisms then the isotopy can be smoothed, that is $f_0, f_1$ are also diffeotopic. But I cannot find a link to this fact. I will very appretiate if somebody let me know where it is written. Only one paper I've manage to find is https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.2221, but there the case when $S$ is torus is exepted. What can be wrong for torus?

Comment: Did you check Earle and Eells papers? The simplest proof I know is to use the interpolation given by the Beltrami equation, with the interpolating Beltrami differential of the form $t\mu$, where $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: Moishe, thank you very much for your hints! In Earle and Eells paper The Diffeomorphism Group of a Compact Riemann Surface I found that the group of diffeomorpfisms of the torus that are homotopic to identity and leave one point fixed  is contractible. Does it mean that all thouse homeomorphisms are diffeotopic to identity? Since the group is contractible, one can find a path connecting the diffeomorphism with identity, and the path in the space of diffeomorphisms (with C^1-topology) is the diffeotopy?

Comment: That's right...